# Starting docker container using existing iproute2 network namespace

Tags: linux, docker, networking, docker-compose

How can i restrict a docker container to run inside an existing iproute2-style network namespace?

```
ip netns exec mynetns docker-compose up
```

does not work (unsurprisingly).

EDIT on comment:

```
$ docker network create --opt com.docker.network.bridge.name=dockerbridge dockernet
$ ip link set dockerbridge netns mynetns
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
```

trying to assign the interface of my docker network to the namespace would not work.
i do want to make sure no traffic leaks - so i want to make sure everything is set up before the containers are started. so waiting for the containers to start and then injecting a veth into their netns to link to mynetns seems fragile.
am trying to route the traffic from dockerbridge to/from mynetns's external veth, maybe that's a way.

EDIT 2:
a solution for me was to create an external network using

```
docker network create --opt com.docker.network.bridge.name=dockerbridge dockernet
```

and using iproute2 tools to route all traffic from dockerbridge through mynetns's outer veth.
i had to adjust my docker-compose.yml to include

```
somecontainer:
   dns: 8.8.8.8

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: dockernet
```

ip route's table option helped, so i could set a second default gateway just for the docker-bridges i want to connect to mynetns.

Comment: Create a docker network with bridge driver and assign docker network interface of this network to the iproute2 network namespace. Then run docker-compose with this docker network as a it's network. Or create a tun device and connect it to the iproutr2 network namespace and create a bridge to the docker network interface.